# RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object while getting polygon points fron DB

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7, recursion

I m trying to draw the stored polygon points on google map when user clicks on the map. I use postgres database. I successfully stored the polygons into DB. When i try to auto draw the polygon points i get an recursion error. Here is my code

```
class drawPolygon(Base):

    __tablename__ = "tbl_data_area"      

    id =  Column(Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    area = Column(Geometry('Polygon'))
    name = Column( Text )

    _poly  = None

    def getPoly(self):
        if not self._poly:
            self._poly = to_shape(self.area)//i get error here
        return self._poly

    def getAreaPoints(self):
        return self.getPoly().area
    area = property(getAreaPoints)
```

I don't know whats wrong in self.area. when the line self._poly = to_shape(self.area) executes I get this error RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object. I m struck with this. Can any one help please.

Comment: `self.area` calls `getAreaPoints(self)` which calls `self.getPoly()` which uses `self.area` which calls `getAreaPoints(self)` which calls `self.getPoly()` which uses `self.area` which calls `getAreaPoints(self)` which calls `self.getPoly()` which uses `self.area`......

Comment: In other words, `self.area` is not the column, it is the `area = property(getAreaPoints)` property you defined. Perhaps you wanted to rename that property?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: It worked by Changing the Property name. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have both a column and a property named `area`:

```
area = Column(Geometry('Polygon'))

# ...

def getAreaPoints(self):
    return self.getPoly().area
area = property(getAreaPoints)
```

The latter replaced the former. As such, `self.getPoly()` uses the *property* when accessing `self.area`, and the property calls `self.getPoly()` again.

Rename either the column or the property if you wanted to use the column in the `getPoly()` method.

Comment: @Martijin Pieters : One more Question. I want to return the list of polygon points like area1,area2,area3 so that i can call that in another class then to pass it to the javascript. How can i do that.

Comment: @martijin how can we do like self.getpoly().area ??

Comment: I have no idea what `to_shape()`; what type of object does it return?

Comment: @MartijnPieters in my opinion dot operator is used obly with the object ..is self.getpoly() returning an object ??